# Is it possible to access Jenkins build status in execute shell?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

Is there a way to have a script being run from an execute shell step access the build status as well as other information about the build? (e.g. build number, start/end time, etc)

I need to update a wiki page with a script with the information about the build.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user1432893 has answered.. but that wont be helpful if you want to get the build status(passed or failed). because exceute shell is part of your build.. only build status is updated after build step..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build status information gets saved into simple XML files. Take a look at
`{jenkins-directory}/jobs/{job-name}/builds/{build-number}/build.xml`. You can use symbolic links like lastSuccessfulBuild instead of specifying a build number if you want.

You'll find all information about the build there: build status, start time, duration, etc. Parse the XML file or just use grep in a bash script.

If you don't want to use the filesystem you can use [Jenkins API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

But in any case, once you got a script that can determine build parameters and update your wiki page, you can put it into another Jenkins job and trigger it automatically (for example, with the [BuildResultTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin)).

Comment: i know that jenkins is storing config and data in XML files.Is there a way to configure it to store in database (mysql , postgres ...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jenkins own API to get the build status while the job is running, which works like a charm. Be aware that i'm using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) To parse the json response.

To get this to work simply add a shell script and execute the following command: `BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}api/json | jq -r '.result')`

[image: Execute shell step]

Which results in the following:

[image: Job console]

Comment: i get "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 18" when i run "BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}api/json | jq -r '.result')"

Comment: Can't test it at the moment because i have no jenkins available, but what is returned by `curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}api/json`? Check the output and see if there is anything in there for you.

Comment: the solution is to use ${BUILD_URL} of finished build and not the current one. 
 short_description = $(curl -g -u pseudo:token--silent "http://172.16.4.26:8080/job/docker-hello-world-spring-boot/77/api/json?pretty=true" | jq -r '.actions[0].causes[0]."shortDescription"') this gives me unkown command shor_description why ?

Comment: Post your json here: https://jqplay.org/ and share to get help.

Answer (score -3):

While executing a build, [Jenkins set environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) you can use in your script.

also refer to the detailes on how to use it -

`%VAR%` in batch files and `$VAR` from inside the Jenkins job configuration page

Comment: There is no environment variable exposing the build status, which was the first information asked in the question...

Comment: Indeed. No BUILD_STATUS or RESULT or anything in env.